# Unity error error CS1061 first person movement script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

IM NOT GOOD AT ENGLISH

I'm trying to make first person movement for my unity game after a guide by Natty Creations, but I got stuck and cant't find any solution. This is the two error messages:

> (15,30): error CS1061: 'PlayerInput' does not contain a definition for
> 'Onfoot' and no accessible extension method 'Onfoot' accepting a first
> argument of type 'PlayerInput' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> (22,15): error CS1061: 'PlayerMotor' does not contain a definition for
> 'ProccessMove' and no accessible extension method 'ProccessMove'
> accepting a first argument of type 'PlayerMotor' could be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my script:

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private PlayerInput.OnFootActions onFoot;

    private PlayerMotor motor;    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        onFoot = playerInput.Onfoot;
        motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        motor.ProccessMove(onFoot.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>());
    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        onFoot.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        onFoot.Disable();
    }
```

`

Please help!

I tried to find typos, but didn't find any according to the tutorial.

[EDIT] it seems like it’s easy to understand the problem IF YOU SPEAK ENGLISH, but the question CLEARLY says that I’m not good at English. Can someone please explain it more easily?!?!

Comment: Well its right. What can we say?

Comment: I don’t understand english very well… I can’t really understand what the messages mean

Comment: Well. Take the second error. It says  you tried to call processMove. There is no method on that class called that. So it throws the error. The errors are specific

Comment: Maybe there is a Stack Overflow site in your language?  Good luck!

Comment: Sadly there isn’t

Comment: Sure that it shouldn't maybe rather be `ProcessMove` (single `c`) and `OnFoot` (capital `F`) ..? that would at least be without spelling mistakes and following the general naming conventions ...

Comment: The capital F solved it, but the other one didnt

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be linked to the inputmanager he is using in the tutorial, be sure to use same unity version he uses and the process he does at start with the inputmanager, be sure to follow that. I dont use that version but I know the inputmanager changed so using older version can make the program give error like this